# Delete record in <ui:repeat> jsf 2.0 tag on clicking delete button on that record. Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I am new to JSF 2.0. I got stuck in deleting record from the database. When delete button of a particular record is fired it should delete from database using Hibernate. Here are some snippets attached, help me out.

**.XHTML**

```
<ui:repeat var="ruleVar" value="#{repricing.repricingRules}">
<div class="col-md-3">#{ruleVar.name}</div>
<div class="col-md-7">#{ruleVar.description}</div>
<div>
      <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{repricing.Deleterule}"  >
           <f:param name="ruleID" value="#{ruleVar.id}"></f:param>
      </h:commandLink>  
</div> 
</ui:repeat>
```

**bean.java**

```
public void  Deleterule() {
    System.out.println("bean");
    String ruleId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
            .get("ruleID");

}
```

When I click on this delete button I could not see the word **bean** in console.From bean I will return the id from **Bean->Boimpl->Daoimpl**

**DaoImpl**

```
public void delete(int rep){
        repricingDao.delete("from table where id="+rep);

    }
```

So first I need to send **id** from **JSF** page to **Bean**.

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what the problem is you are facing. What is stopping you from calling the delete method?

Comment: Please read [ask] and specifically the [mcve] part and improve your question. Also read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: hi @Gimby, As I said when I click on delete button. ID of that record is not getting into  bean! Thanks

Comment: @srikanthpragallapati absolutely nowhere do you say that. Can't say what could be wrong from only very minimalistic snippets. Read the links that Kukeltje provided for more information on what you could do to get actual answers.

Comment: @srikanthpragallapati have you set "repricing" in faces-config.xml file to java class bean.java? also your <h:commandLink> should be inside <h:form> tag

Comment: @nileshvirkar Ya problem have been solved i have nested forms so I could not fire the method. Thanks!